React JS: Sharing Data between components in both directions
currently i have to work on the frontend part and need a communication between my two components:
Child-Component:
export function CondisAddressSearchToggle(isToggled: any) : JSX.Element {
const [data, setData] = React.useState<boolean>();

function onChanged (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {        
    isToggled(data);
};
return (
    <div className="btnArea">
        <label className="desc" id="toggleBtnLabel" htmlFor="toggleBtn">Suche in:</label>
        <input
        className="toggle"
        id='toggleBtn'
        name='toggleBtn'
        placeholder=''
        type='checkbox'
        onChange={(e) => onChanged}
        />
    </div>
)}

Parent-Component:
export function CondisAddressSearchComponent({ name }: ICondisAddressSearchProps): JSX.Element {
const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = React.useState<boolean>(); 

return (
    <form
    >
        <header>
            <h2>
                {name}
            </h2>
        </header>
        <div>
        <CondisAddressSearchToggle isToggled={[isToggled, setIsToggled]} />
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
       
                <button
                    id="searchBtn"
                    name="searchBtn"
                    tabIndex={6}
                    type="submit"
                    value="Submit">
                    In {isToggled ? 'OLAV' : 'CONDIS '} suchen 
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
)};

Now i need to have the prop: isToggled as well in the parent to display the buttons-text correctly, as also in the child to get their some stlings and functionality handled
Can someone help me a little bit, cause the react.dev documentation confuses me a little bit about that topic

There are several mistakes in your child component

If you are passing isToggled={[isToggled, setIsToggled]} from parent and getting it as CondisAddressSearchToggle(isToggled: any) in child then you have to use

function onChanged (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {        
    isToggled.isToggled[1](data);
};


onChange={(e) => onChanged} should be onChange={(e) => onChanged()} or onChange={onChanged}
props should be passed separately to fix the confusion.

You can try
export function CondisAddressSearchToggle({isToggled: boolean, setIsToggled: any}) : JSX.Element {
const [data, setData] = React.useState<boolean>();

function onChanged (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {        
    setIsToggled(!isToggled);
};
return (
    <div className="btnArea">
        <label className="desc" id="toggleBtnLabel" htmlFor="toggleBtn">Suche in:</label>
        <input
        className="toggle"
        id='toggleBtn'
        name='toggleBtn'
        placeholder=''
        type='checkbox'
        onChange={(e) => onChanged()}
        />
    </div>
)}

and parent
export function CondisAddressSearchComponent({ name }: ICondisAddressSearchProps): JSX.Element {
const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = React.useState<boolean>(false); 

return (
    <form
    >
        <header>
            <h2>
                {name}
            </h2>
        </header>
        <div>
        <CondisAddressSearchToggle isToggled={isToggled} setIsToggled={setIsToggled} />
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
       
                <button
                    id="searchBtn"
                    name="searchBtn"
                    tabIndex={6}
                    type="submit"
                    value="Submit">
                    In {isToggled ? 'OLAV' : 'CONDIS '} suchen 
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
)};


Many Thanks, but this still doesnt solve my problem, cause i dont get the information in the searchBtn
there was a mistake in the child-component, with this snippet it works as expected:
function onChanged (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {                 setIsToggled(!isToggled);                 console.log(isToggled)     };

@PatrickSeewald Yes, that is something that I guessed you intended to do when your question has isToggled(data); and I corrected to `setIsToggled(data), I thought you omitted lines where you fill the data with boolean.
